# AWS Autoscale Load Balancing with Cloudformation

Tags: autoscaling, amazon-elb, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create an EC2 instance, that will use autoscaling, attached to a load balancer.

Unfortunately, I'm getting the error

```
The availability zones of the specified subnets and the AutoScalingGroup do not match
```

However, this is my current Cloudformation script:

```json
"ApiAutoScaling" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "VPCZoneIdentifier" : [ "subnet-5ff05206", "subnet-b1109fc6", "subnet-948ce5f1" ],
    "InstanceId" : {
      "Ref" : "ApiEC2"
    },
    "MaxSize" : 3,
    "MinSize" : 1,
    "LoadBalancerNames" : [ "Api" ]
  }
},
"ApiLoadBalancer" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
  "Properties" : {
    "LoadBalancerName" : "Api",
    "Listeners" : [
      {
        "InstancePort" : "80",
        "InstanceProtocol" : "HTTP",
        "LoadBalancerPort" : "80",
        "Protocol" : "HTTP"
      },
      {
        "InstancePort" : "80",
        "InstanceProtocol" : "HTTP",
        "LoadBalancerPort" : "443",
        "Protocol" : "HTTPS",
        "SSLCertificateId" : "arn:aws:iam::xxx"
      }
    ],
    "SecurityGroups" : [ "sg-a88444cc" ],
    "Subnets" : [ "subnet-5ff05206", "subnet-b1109fc6", "subnet-948ce5f1" ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, my subnet list is the same for both my autoscaling group and my load balancer. Clearly I've misunderstood how this is supposed to work, but I can't work it out.

Comment: If more information is required, please let me know.

Comment: Try specifying the `AvailabilityZones` property for the auto scaling group. The default is for it to use all of them, so if your subnets only use a subnet of the zones, you would get this error message.

Comment: You are correct. I had tried this manually with no luck, but the trick was to use [Fn::GetAZs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getavailabilityzones.html), even just `"AvailabilityZones" : { "Fn::GetAZs" : "" }` works. I believe that, as you say, the default is to use them all, but the function will return only the ones you actually *can* use. A bit weird but still, if you want to make that an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the `AvailabilityZones` property for the auto scaling group. The default is for it to use all of them, so if your subnets only use a subnet of the zones, you would get this error message.

(As pointed out in the comments, `"AvailabilityZones" : { "Fn::GetAZs" : "" }` should do the trick.)